# How to display parent menu item in node template? Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

How do i display the parent menu item in the node template?

I want to display parent menu item along with current page; but i dont need others.

Edit: I enabled menu breadcrumb module and added the following code:

```
<?php              
                $menuParent = menu_get_active_trail();
                if (sizeof ($menuParent) >= 2 && $menuParent[2]) {
                     $menuParent = $menuParent[1]['link_title'];
                     print $menuParent; 
                } 
            ?>
```

It is working fine, but I am getting an error for the pages which doesn't have 2nd level navigation:
Error: Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in include()

I thought my condition sizeof will take care of the problem, but not working.

Answer (score 8):

Use PHP array tools to get you the right item in the array:

```
<?php
  $menuParent = menu_get_active_trail();
  //get rid of the last item in the array as it is the current page
  $menuParentPop = array_pop($menuParent);
  //Just grab the last item in the array now
  $menuParent = end($menuParent);
  //if it is not the home page and it is not an empty array
  if(!empty($menuParent) && $menuParent['link_path'] != ''){
    print $menuParent['title'];
  } else{
    print $title;
  }
?>
```

Comment: If you want to get the root of the menu path, it should be in `$menuParent[1]`. $menuParent[0] will always return the front page, so make sure to check if $menuParent[1] is set before trying to access it if on the <front> page

Answer (score 0):

You're checking `$menuParent[2]` but then using `$menuParent[1]`.  Maybe check `$menuParent[1]`:

```
if (sizeof ($menuParent) >= 2 && $menuParent[1]) {
```

PHP's arrays are zero-indexed, so slot `1` is the second slot.